# Using variable query operators only when they are not empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say that on a movie website you can set filters for the movies that will be shown to you.

As far as I am now these preferences are saved to the User model as a map. This map might look like the following object:

```
preferences: {
  yearFrom: "2000"
  yearTo: "2020"
  actors: ["Denzel Washington", "Tom Hanks", "Morgan Freeman"]
}
```

Before the movies are shown to you, a view controller wil first get the current user:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
```

Then get the preferences map from the user: (It's a map so I made it into into a string first before converting it to an object)

```
const preferencesObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.preferences));
```

At this point the question arises: How to build up the query for all movies when one of the variable query operators comming from the preferencesObject might be empty? So far I've got:

```
const preferedMovies = await Movies.find({
    year: { $gte: preferencesObject.yearFrom, $lte: preferencesObject.yearTo },
    actor: { $in: JSON.parse(preferencesObject.actors) }
});
```

If actors is empty I would like to include all actors, but this point 0 movies will be shown. If yearFrom is empty I would like to default to 0. There might be many more preferences that can be set, so how can you check if a variable operator is empty and then not use it or set a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the query object from the `preferencesObject` first, then pass it to `find()`. Something like:

```
let query = {
  year: { $gte: 0 }  // default: 0
};
if (preferencesObject.yearFrom) query.year.$gte = preferencesObject.yearFrom;
if (preferencesObject.yearTo ) query.year.$lte= preferencesObject.yearTo ;
if (preferencesObject.actors && preferencesObject.actors.length) {
  query.actor = { $in: preferencesObject.actors };
}
const preferedMovies = await Movies.find(query)...
```

Comment: So because of the $ signs and checking other mongoose stuf like $exists I forgot it's just a Javacript object. Thanks.